# FileUploadInputElement disable All Files option

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-html

I want to implement a file picker that would only upload image filetypes and hide the options button.

```
InputElement uploadInput = FileUploadInputElement();
uploadInput.accept = 'image/*'
uploadInput.click();
```

However, when selecting a file, the user can select the option > all files.

[Image types](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xUXpw.png)

[All files are enabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CwQzK.png)

How do I hide the options button? In the [mdn docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file), when selecting a file, the options button is hidden. I want to do it just like that.